# How can I use multiple animations on one widget on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want to use both `AnimatedPositioned` and `AnimatedSize` on my project. But when I put `AnimatedSize` as a child of `AnimatedPositioned` it messes up the stack. How can I do it properly?

Here is the code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bitch',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _state = true;
  double _size = 20.0;
  bool _large = false;
  bool selected = false;
  double _width = 92.0;
  bool _largewidth = false;
  double _height = 48.0;
  bool _largeheight = false;

  void _changeState() {
    _state = !_state;
    _size = _large ? 20.0 : 16.0;
    _large = !_large;
    _width = _largewidth ? 92.0 : 40.0;
    _largewidth = !_largewidth;
    _height = _largeheight ? 48.0 : 40.0;
    selected = !selected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff2d3748),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              //Fade out
              AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: _state ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'OKR İNCE AYAR',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                top: selected ? 44.0 : 6.7,
                left: 20,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                child: AnimatedSize(
                  curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  vsync: this,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: _size,
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage('https://i.hizliresim.com/hj65gdg.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 12,
                left: 72,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _state ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Sertan Hakkı İmamoğlu',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '.NET Intern',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                vsync: this,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white10,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/firsticon.png'),
                    color: Color(0xffe2e8f0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                vsync: this,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white10,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/secondicon.png'),
                    color: Color(0xffe2e8f0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                vsync: this,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white10,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/thirdicon.png'),
                    color: Color(0xffe2e8f0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                bottom: 20,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _changeState();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'State Değiştir',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Quicksand', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do your way

Comment: Can you add your code snippet and a gif/video the animation you are trying to archive and the errors you are getting?

Comment: @ArturSikora For example, my button was at the bottom on my stack (stack is the biggest widget) and my one widget (circleavatar) was 20 pixels away from left but when I used two animated widgets together, it looks like it resets itself. For example, the button was at the top and circle avatar had no padding like it used to have

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: is `State Değiştir` button just for test case?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I didn't understand what you mean but it is for the change of states. The label means 'Change the State'

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get that . Can you add an image that you like you to archive. Also, current code snippet providing overlay issue(maybe thing you don't want)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry I don't have an image of what I want to achieve and that overlay issue is  the reason why I posted this, I'm aware of the problem. Thanks anyway for trying to help :)

Comment: Do you want that text at the backside of everything ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no

Comment: check `RelativePositionedTransition` which animates between two `Rect`s (thus combining position and size)